# jQuery script not working in google chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome

As odd as it may seem I have a part of my script that looks like this... php is controlling access to my jQuery function; please excuse the fact that there maybe some redundant code here, but allow me to explain the main issue here.

Here is a code excerpt of php:

```
<?php
        if($user_info['ACTIVE'] == 'Y')
            {
                require("jQuery/main_function.js");
                require("edit_profile.php");
            }elseif(!isset($_GET['resend']))
            {
                echo '<div id="profile_info"><p>In order to modify or setup your seller profile your account must be activated.<br />
                Check your email; if you did not receive an email, <a href="profile.php?resend">Click here</a> to have another one dispatched.</p>';
                echo '<p>You can however complete your contact information <a href="user_contact.php">here</a>';
            }
```

As you can see in the php code, if the user is active, as determined from a database call, it will require main_function.js in the html, thus dropping this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function option_click(elementId)
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('testing1');
            var defaultString = "Upload";
            var elementNum = elementId.substr(elementId.length-1, 1);
            switch($('#'+elementId).val())
            {
                case 'Video':
                {
                    alert('testing in chrome');
                    $('.set_time'+elementNum).prop('type', 'hidden');
                    $('.product_upload'+elementNum).prop('type', 'file');
                    $('.content_upload'+elementNum).html(defaultString + ' a ' + 'video file:');
                    break;  
                }
                case 'Time':
                {
                    $('.content_upload'+elementNum).html('How much time?');
                    $('.product_upload'+elementNum).prop('type', 'hidden');
                    $('.set_time'+elementNum).prop('type', 'text');
                    break;
                }
                case 'Music/Audio':
                {
                    $('.set_time'+elementNum).prop('type', 'hidden');
                    $('.product_upload'+elementNum).prop('type', 'file');
                    $('.content_upload'+elementNum).html(defaultString + ' a ' + 'music file');
                    break;
                }
                case 'Ebook':
                {
                    $('.set_time'+elementNum).prop('type', 'hidden');
                    $('.product_upload'+elementNum).prop('type', 'file');
                    $('.content_upload'+elementNum).html(defaultString + ' an ' + 'ebook file');
                    break;  
                }
                case 'Tutorial/Docs':
                {
                    $('.set_time'+elementNum).prop('type', 'hidden');
                    $('.product_upload'+elementNum).prop('type', 'file');
                    $('.content_upload'+elementNum).html(defaultString + ' a ' + 'tutorial file');  
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

in the middle of my code...

Works fine in all browsers except google chrome? Why?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the console that you can share with us?

Comment: you can't use require("jQuery/main_function.js"); use include instead of read the content and echo it before php loads.

Comment: @JapanPro Why would `include` be better than `require`?

Comment: Nothing in console... As I said, it works perfectly in all browsers except google chrome. I have scoured chrome for errors, but it shows none, it simply doesn't execute that bit of code.

Comment: Why do you have those curly braces in your switch statement?

Comment: how would using `include` over `require` affect how the browser view the page? @JapanPro is chrome generating any errors? and how are you calling the fuction?

Comment: How and where is `option_click()` called? For the code you've shown it would not be called in _any_ browser... And why do you have a document ready handler there?

Comment: `optgroup label="Select an option">
                            <option id="video0" onclick="option_click(this.id)">Video</option>`

Comment: What version of Chrome are you testing against?

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks... took that out, didn't change anything though... please stay on topic lol.

Comment: It is the latest version of Chrome as I just downloaded it this morning after my boss tried testing my live version in chrome and found it didn't work.

Comment: Does the first alert "testing1" hit? Does an alert hit if you place it outside of the ready() function?

Comment: The alert 'testing1' does not even hit... it's as if it's not reading the script element at all... I have other scripts running such as one that hides an element if a button is clicked, and it works fine, even in chrome.

Comment: Yes the alert hits if I place one outside of the ready function.

Comment: In Web Developer console, if you invoke "option_click()" explicitly, do you see the alert?

Comment: Cool - at least you know your script is being called! It could be related to the Answer posted by Sheikh (regarding the val())?

Comment: Actually - a good test is to include the default case. At least then it'll hit if the other conditions are not met. Good luck man!

Comment: When I include a default case it doesn't execute the default either.

Comment: Can you try alerting "jQuery.isReady" outside the ready() function? Does that alert true or false?

Comment: did that... outside the ready function it says false, inside, of course it states true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are swirching option's value like

```
switch($('#'+elementId).val())
```

but in your element (option) I didn't see any `value` assigned (from the comment you provided)

```
<option id="video0" onclick="option_click(this.id)">Video</option>
```

**Update:**

Your approach (not working in Chrome)

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
       <option id="volvo" onclick="option_click(this.id)">Volvo</option>
       <option id="saab" onclick="option_click(this.id)">Saab</option>
   </optgroup>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7V3pZ/4/).

Proper way (Working in all browsers)

```
<select onchange="option_click(this.value)">
    <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
        <option value="volvo" id="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab" id="saab">Saab</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7V3pZ/3/).

[An example with switch statement here](http://jsfiddle.net/7V3pZ/5/).

Comment: The value becomes Video... typically the value is what's between the option tags.

Comment: As stated previously, this works in firefox, ie, opera etc, just not chrome